# Change the mouse-select color in Jupyterlab 3

Tags: jupyter, highlight, jupyter-lab

I want to change the color of selected/highlighted text by mouse in input cells in Jupyterlab 3. I am using the light theme, however the highlighted text appears difficult to read in input cells. If I hightlight text with my mouse in the output cells, it is absolutely fine. Please see the attached image. Ideally I want both of my highlights have the same light blue color.

[image]

The extensions I am running are below. I have only 3 different themes - light, dark, and darcula. Jupyter lab is version v3.0.16. The complete stack is Jupyterhub with dockerspawner on Ubuntu 20.04.2. I am using Google Chrome browser on Win 10, the same problem happens in Edge.

[image]

Comment: Ouch, that should not be lik that. It does not look like that on my machine. Could you list you extensions and themes (`jupyter labextension list`) you have installed, exact version of JupyterLab and the name of the browser and operating system that you use please?

Comment: @krassowski Edited my OP. If you need any more info I will do best to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from `theme-darcula`. Strangely it spill styles even when not in use. If you are not using it (as you say you are using the Light theme) you can remove it with:

```
pip uninstall theme-darcula
```

(or appropriate conda command if you installed it with conda). After restarting JupyterLab the issue goes away for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are so fast with your responses it is unbelievable! Unreal.

Comment: :) I opened an issue to let the author know about it (https://github.com/telamonian/theme-darcula/issues/32) so hopefully it can get fixed in a future release.

Comment: A [patch fixing this issue](https://github.com/telamonian/theme-darcula/pull/33) has just got merged so it should work better in the next release :)